# Can the strict triangle inequality hold in a length space?

Tags: inequality, metric-spaces, curves, arc-length

Let $(M, d)$ be a [metric space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_space#Definition) where

- (0) for relevance: set $M$ contains at least three distinct elements and

distance function $d : M \times M \to \mathbb R$ explicitly satisfies

- (1) non-negativity: $d[ \, x, y \, ] \ge 0$ (where $x, y \in M$ are not necessarily distinct),
- (2) identity of indiscernibles: $d[ \, x, y \, ] = 0 \, \iff \, x \equiv y$,
- (3) symmetry: $d[ \, y, x \, ] = d[ \, x, y \, ]$, and
- (4) the general triangle inequality (a.k.a. inclusive subadditivity): $d[ \, x, z \, ] \le d[ \, x, y \, ] + d[ \, y, z \, ]$ for any three (not necessarily all distinct) $x, y, z \in M$.

Now consider the following two additional conditions:

- (a) the strict triangle inequality (a.k.a. exclusive subadditivity): $d[ \, x, z \, ] \lt d[ \, x, y \, ] + [ \, y, z \, ] \iff (y \not\equiv x \hbox{ and } y \not\equiv z)$,
  which includes the case that $x, y, z$ are all pairwise distinct;
- (b) metric space $(M, d)$ is a [length space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intrinsic_metric#Definitions);
  which shall be defined here explicitly and suitably generally as follows:
  $ \, $
  $\forall \, x, z \in M \, | \,  x \not\equiv z : (\exists \, y \in M \, | \, d[ \, x, y \, ] \lt d[ \, x, z \, ] \hbox{ and } d[ \, y, z \, ] \lt d[ \, x, z \, ]) \implies $
  $ \, $
  $d[ \, x, z \, ] = \text{inf}_{\{\forall \, C \subset M | \, \exists \, q \, \in \, C \, : \, q \not\equiv x \text{ and } q \not\equiv z\}}{\Large[} \, \text{sup}_{\{ n \in \mathbb N \}}{\large[} \, $
  ${\left\{ \text{inf}_{ \{ \forall \text{ permutations } p \, : n \rightarrow C \} } \!\! \left[ \sum_{k = 1}^n d[ \, p_{(k - 1)}, p_{(k)} \, ] \right] | {x \equiv p_{(0)} \hbox{ and } z \equiv p_{(n)} \hbox{ and } (\forall \, k \le n : p_{(k)} \in C)} \right\}} $
  $ \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad {\large]} \, {\Large]},$
  where the expression part
  $ \text{sup}_{\{ n \in \mathbb N \}} \left[ \, {\left\{ \text{inf}_{ \{ \forall \text{ permutations } p \, : n \rightarrow C \} } \!\! \left[ \sum_{k = 1}^n d[ \, p_{(k - 1)}, p_{(k)} \, ] \right] | {x \equiv p_{(0)} \hbox{ and } z \equiv p_{(n)} \hbox{ and } (\forall \, k \le n : p_{(k)} \in C)} \right\}} \right] $
  is to be regarded as (general, possibly polygonal) [length of chain $C$ between $x$ and $z$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve#Length_of_a_curve).

Surely both these conditions (a) as well as (b) are separately consistent with conditions (0) through (4) stated above, describing a corresponding metric space.

**My question:**
Are these conditions (a) and (b) consistent with each other?
Or in other words: Can the strict triangle inequality hold in a length space?

Answer (score 3):

In particular, such a space contains no nonconstant minimizing geodesics. Examples of complete metric spaces without **any** nonconstant minimizing geodesics  are constructed in [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/15592/intrinsic-metric-with-no-geodesics?rq=1) mathoverflow answer. You should check these examples to see if they satisfy your condition (you may have to modify the construction though).

Edit. Here is a construction of what you are asking for. I will leave you to fill in the details.

Definition. A point $m$ in a metric space $(X,d)$ is an *$\epsilon$-midpoint* between distinct points $x, y\in M$ if
$$
\frac{1}{2} d(x,y)< \min(d(m,x), d(m,y))\le \max( d(m,x), d(m,y) ) < \frac{1}{2} d(x,y) + \epsilon.
$$

Definition. A metric space $(X,d)$ is *strict* if any triple of distinct points in $X$ satisfies strict triangle inequalities.

Lemma. Given a countable strict metric space $(X,d)$, $\epsilon>0$ and two distinct points $x,y\in M$, there exists a strict metric $d'$ on $X':= X \sqcup \{m\}$ extending the metric $d$ on $X$, such that $m$ is an  $\epsilon$-midpoint between $x, y$.

Now, here is a construction of a (countable) strict length metric space $(X,d)$.

Start with a 2-point set $X_1=\{x,y\}$, $d_1(x,y)=1$. Then, using Lemma, inductively build finite strict metric spaces $(X_n,d_n)$ by adding $\epsilon$-midpoints  (where each $\epsilon$ is of the form $\frac{1}{i}$ for some $i\in {\mathbb N}$), in such a way that for each $n$ and every pair of points $x,y\in X_n$  and every $i\in {\mathbb N}$, there exists $k=k(n,x,y,m)$ such that on the $k$-th stage of the construction, we add to $X_{k}$ an  $\frac{1}{i}$-midpoint between $x$ and $y$. (This requires a certain enumeration of ${\mathbb N}^3$ where the first two coordinates in ${\mathbb N}^3$ represent points in our finite metric spaces and the last coordinate corresponds to the index $i$ as above.) 
Lastly, take
$$
X:= \bigcup_{n} X_n
$$
where the metric $d$ on $X$ is defined as the direct limit of the metrics $d_n$,  i.e. it restricts to the metric $d_n$ on $X_n$ for each $n$. Then $(X,d)$ is a strict length metric space.

Note that $(X,d)$ will be incomplete and will not be a path-metric space.

Comment: Moishe Cohen: "_In particular, such a space contains no nonconstant minimizing geodesics._" -- But is such a metric space that you describe even called "length space"?? (And even: what exactly is the definition of "_nonconstant minimizing geodesic_" in suitable generality?) "_Examples [...] are constructed in this mathoverflow answer. You should check these_" -- Too bad I got, for all intents and purposes, kicked out off mathoverflow; due to having asked questions pretty much like the one above ... (Still: +1 for your interest and effort.)

Comment: @user12262: Yes, it is a length space (in the standard sense), which is what makes this example so amazing! I do not have much time to think about this, but read the example and see if it satisfies the stronger property you are asking.

Comment: Moishe Cohen: Well, I see that [the question there](https://mathoverflow.net/q/15592) relates to mine here, but doesn't quite match it: A space 'with intrinsic metric' (as defined there) is indeed an example of a length space; but in turn: a space satisfying the strict triangle inequality (of my definition) surely is an example of a space which 'has no nontrivial min.zing geodesics.' So the example given over there doesn't necessarily make an affirmative answer here quite yet. Moreover, I'm stymied by its jargon or assumptions: '$c_0$'? 'distance element $\|dx\|_{\infty}$'? '$m$-th position'??